# How to I get the same millisecond for Java and Objective C

Tags: ios, date

I can get milliseconds in Java with:

```
Date date=new Date() ;  
System.out.println("Today is " +date.getTime());
```

How do I get milliseconds in objective C?  I have to have the same result for both code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/889380/how-can-i-get-a-precise-time-for-example-in-milliseconds-in-objective-c

Comment: Did you try searching before asking? In the Related area, I found this one as second question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3990295/in-iphoneobjective-c-how-do-i-get-the-current-date-formatted-in-miliseconds-to?rq=1

Comment: Since ObjC is C, you should just be able to use `time()*1000` from `time.h`.

Comment: (And honestly, if you need a predictable time representation, go with a timezone-aware ISO8601 one.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for Java Date.getTime() is:

> Returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT
>   represented by this Date object.

For Objective-C the analogous method is:

```
- (NSTimeInterval)timeIntervalSince1970
```

> Return Value: The interval between the receiver and the reference
>   date, 1 January 1970, GMT.

An NSTimeInterval is a `double` in seconds. So, this does it:

```
  llrint (1000.0 * [date timeIntervalSince1970]);
```

to get you a `long` (as Java produces).

Note: 'duplicate' answers do not produce a `long` as the Java interface does; they produce a `double`.

Comment: +1 This directly answers the question of a Java-compatible ms count. Note that `llrint` may be more accurate than `lrint` because a Java long is always 64 bits.